question about triangle-free graph is 3-coloured
Let $G$ be a simple, undirected graph with 20 vertices without triangles. can we color $G$ with 3 colors so that 2 adjacent vertices are different colors.
Mentioning triangle-free graph is 3-coloured I thought of Grotzsch theorem but however it is only true for a planar graph, so I think that for a non-planar graph there will be a maximum value of $n$ for triangle-free graph with $n$ vertices is 3-coloured and I wonder what that number is, is it 20 and if not, how can we prove it for this case $n=20$. I can't think of any good solution but I think the probability method seems to be effective in this situation, it's just that I don't really understand much about it so I haven't solved it yet, if you have any contributions please help me, thank you very much

The smallest triangle-free graph with chromatic number 4 is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grötzsch_graph

@caduk Thanks but i thinks it not really relevant to the issue here

This example shows that starting from $n=11$, there are triangle-free graphs that are not 3-colorable. If it does not answer your question, then I don't understand it and you might improve it.

@caduk i will read and check again, thanks you

@caduk ye thanks you, that my fault
